# SQL query with condition in second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `rooms` and `scheduled`. In the scheduled-table, there are entries with a `begin_time`, `end_time` and a `room_id` - which displays when the rooms are booked. The rooms-table contains entries with an `id` for every room.

The `begin_time` and `end_time` only contain the hours, so for example '9' and '11', which indicate that the room is booked from 9 till 11.

I want to display a list of the rooms that are currently available. To do this, I need a query that select all room id's from the `rooms` table, on the condition that there is no entry in `scheduled` for the current hour (so the current hour does not exist between `begin_time` and `end_time` for the room id).

I tried the following:

`` SELECT DISTINCT id
, room_nr
FROM rooms
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT room_id
    FROM scheduled
    WHERE rooms.id = scheduled.room_id
    AND date = CURDATE()
    AND HOUR(CURDATE()) NOT BETWEEN `begin_time` AND `end_time`) ``

But that does not work, it only shows the rooms for which the `id` is not existing in `scheduled` for the current date - without the time condition. I also tried something with joins, but I don't really understand them. How can I make a query that returns the `id`'s from the `rooms`-table under the described condition?

---

UPDATE:
I builded the database in this MySQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecd82c

Comment: And the syntax error is?

Comment: I think the problem is your DATE() function. I guess you wanted CURDATE().
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: @notulysses, the syntax error is: ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND HOUR(CURDATE()) NOT BETWEEN `begin_time` AND `end_time` ' at line 12 ```. I tried `CURDATE()` but that does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @BasC you didn't change the DATE on all places. change it here also - AND date = DATE()

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
, room_nr
FROM rooms
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT room_id
    FROM scheduled
    WHERE rooms.id = scheduled.room_id
    AND date = CURDATE()
    AND HOUR(CURTIME()) NOT BETWEEN `begin_time` AND `end_time`)
```

Comment: Thank you, this query does give output and not a syntax error. I think it works! I'm gonna test it a bit further!

Comment: The query works, but does not select the right entries. I will post a SQL-fiddle.

Comment: Your query does select all the `id`'s in `rooms` for which there is no entry in `scheduled` on the current date. The time condition does not work yet. Can you look into that?

Comment: @BasC can you give an example of values in begin_time AND end_time fields?

Comment: I edited my answer. CURDATE() gives us only date so try with CURTIME(). you'll get an integer between 0 and 23.

Comment: It now works, indeed it had to be `CURTIME()` or `NOW()`. Also I had a double `NOT` (where NOT exists, NOT between), so I removed the `NOT` in `NOT BETWEEN` and now it works!